# Is there a clean way to access private variables inside a Namespace

Tags: javascript, jquery, model-view-controller, namespaces

I am using the Namespace scripts from https://github.com/smith/namespacedotjs to encapsulate my control-specific javascript and jQuery code in my ASP.NET MVC application. Without using namespaces, methods of the same name can interfere with each other and cause undesired behavior.

Here is my **current working code**:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

Namespace('MyCompany.MyApp.ReviseDrawingNumber.AddSheetNumber', {

        SelectDrawingNumbersControl: {
            selectedIds: [],

            setSelectedIds: function() {
                // wire up checkboxes
                $('#DrawingSheetNumbersGrid :checkbox').live('change', function(e) {
                    var $check = $(this);
                    console.log($check);
                    if ($check.is(':checked')) {
                        // add id to selectedIds
                        MyCompany.MyApp.ReviseDrawingNumber.AddSheetNumber.SelectDrawingNumbersControl.selectedIds.push($check.val());
                    }
                    else {
                        // remove id from selectedIds
                        MyCompany.MyApp.ReviseDrawingNumber.AddSheetNumber.SelectDrawingNumbersControl.selectedIds =
                            $.grep(MyCompany.MyApp.ReviseDrawingNumber.AddSheetNumber.SelectDrawingNumbersControl.selectedIds, function(item, index) {
                            return item != $check.val();
                        });
                    }
                });
            }    
        }
    });

</script>
```

However, in the code sample above, notice I am using a variable "selectedIds" which is an array of strings. Since this variable is declared as part of my namespace I am now forced to reference it, from other methods inside the same namespace, by it's fully-qualified path.

Ideally, I would prefer to write something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

Namespace('MyCompany.MyApp.ReviseDrawingNumber.AddSheetNumber', {

        SelectDrawingNumbersControl: {
            selectedIds: [],

            setSelectedIds: function() {
                // wire up checkboxes
                $('#DrawingSheetNumbersGrid :checkbox').live('change', function(e) {
                    var $check = $(this);
                    console.log($check);
                    if ($check.is(':checked')) {
                        // add id to selectedIds
                        selectedIds.push($check.val());
                    }
                    else {
                        // remove id from selectedIds
                        selectedIds = $.grep(selectedIds, function(item, index) {
                            return item != $check.val();
                        });
                    }
                });
            }    
        }
    });

</script>
```

My existing code sample #1 above feels pretty cumbersome - I am used to writing C# and referencing objects from the same namespace without fully qualifying them (i.e. code sample #2).

I have looked at Ben Cherry's [documented module pattern](http://www.adequatelygood.com/2010/3/JavaScript-Module-Pattern-In-Depth), which I started to use; however, passing in the list of all globals needed inside the module code every time you create or update a module seems like a maintenance nightmare.

The namespace solution seems syntactically cleaner and would be absolutely perfect if I could do away with the need to fully qualify "private" variables.

Does anyone have a good solution to this JavaScript dilemma?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way I can think to resolve your problem would be to keep a reference to your control within whichever method you intend to use. Effectively you're just aliasing the classname.

```
        setSelectedIds: function() {
            //keep a reference to SelectDrawingNumbersControl in case we need it
            var that = this;

            // wire up checkboxes
            $('#DrawingSheetNumbersGrid :checkbox').live('change', function(e) {
                var $check = $(this);
                console.log($check);
                if ($check.is(':checked')) {
                    // add id to selectedIds
                    that.selectedIds.push($check.val());
                }
                else {
                    // remove id from selectedIds
                    that.selectedIds =
                        $.grep(that.selectedIds, function(item, index) {
                        return item != $check.val();
                    });
                }
            });
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're making `selectedIds` a public member of your namespace, there's nothing "private" about it.

If you want true privacy, while also giving methods at a sibling level access to the variable, define it inside a closure:

```
(function () {
    var selectedIds = [];

    Namespace('MyCompany.MyApp.ReviseDrawingNumber.AddSheetNumber', {
        SelectDrawingNumbersControl: {
            setSelectedIds: function() {
                // use selectedIds directly
                ...

})();
```

Comment: This works great for local variables, how about private functions?

Comment: Exactly the same way. You can define private functions at the same location `selectedIds` is defined.